# NGINX phpmyadmin http authentication error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have an ubuntu instance running nginx. I have applied nginx http authentication on the directory containing phpmyadmin. Now whenever I go to https://url.com/dir1/dir2/phpmyadmin nginx will return a 403 error instead of going to the index.php inside the phpmyadmin directory. I have used index index.php; both outside and inside my location blocks, but it has had no effect. Only when I comment the http authentication lines in the config file will nginx redirect /phpmyadmin to /phpmyadmin/index.php. By the way this happens with any directory that has the authentication, not only phpmyadmin.

```
    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.







    location /console/admin {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            index index.php;
            auth_basic "Admin Console";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;


    }
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }
    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {




    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  
    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

Any suggestions or solutions to this issue?

Comment: Please post your nginx config

Comment: @ben5556 I put in the config file.

Comment: Hi, you are trying to access https://url.com/console/admin/phpmyadmin and are getting a 403 with the auth ? Does it prompt for credentials and you are entering valid credentials ?

Comment: @ben5556 Yes I am entering the proper credentials. The page is served when I go directly to /console/admin/phpmyadmin/index.php. But not at phpmyadmin/. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Check you directory permissions `/var/www/html/console/admin/phpmyadmin` ...user `nginx` should have appropriate permissions. I did some testing on my end, lack of right permissions reproduced the exact same behavior you are seeing

Comment: Hey @ben5556 I tried doing as you said. I changed ownership of the directory to www-data and also gave other and group read and write access, but I am still having the same issue. Btw I don't see a user named nginx.

Comment: What/ who do you see as `user` in nginx.conf ?

Comment: www-data is the user.

Comment: Quick update: /console/admin/phpmyadmin redirects to /console/admin/phomyadmin/index.php, but /console/admin/phpmyadmin/ doesn't.